# Change Grafana's headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, graphite, grafana

I'm trying to display a Grafana dashboard within a plain PHP page. I followed the website instructions to authentiate with oauth. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer <myToken>";
curl_setopt_array(
    $ch, array( 
    CURLOPT_URL => 'url-to-my-dashboard',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => "HTTP/1.1"
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $output; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The page loads, I get the CSS... but I end up with a 404 error. I discover that Grafana's headers do not allow this kind of actions:

```
Access to Font at 'http://xxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost'
has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm quite sure I need to configure these headers:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "xxx"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, authorization, accept"
```

The problem is I don't know where I shall do it. I've been looking for an .htaccess file for Grafana (or Graphite, which we use with it). I've also tried modifying the Apache2 conf file (/etc/apache2/apache2/conf); after restart, nothing changes...

I'm quite stuck. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you been able to solve your issue? via @JMeterDude

Answer (score 1):

It is the browser that is blocking the requests and not Grafana due to the requests violating the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). For localhost, two websites running on different ports are considered to be two different domains.

You will need to put your Grafana server behind a reverse proxy to allow Cross Origin resource sharing (CORS).

There is an issue describing this with a link to the docs.

- Issue: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/5837
- Docs link: http://docs.grafana.org/v1.9/installation/#graphite-server-config

Extract from the docs (link above) describing the Apache config:

> For Apache 2.x:
>
> ```
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS"
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, authorization, accept"
> ```
>
> Note that using "*" leaves your graphite instance quite open so you
>   might want to consider using "http://my.grafana.com" in place of "*"
>
> If your Graphite web is proteced by basic authentication, you have to
>   enable the HTTP verb OPTIONS. Take note that when using basic auth
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin must not be set to a wildcard, also the
>   header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials must be specified. This looks
>   like the following for Apache:
>
> ```
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin    "http://mygrafana.com:5656"
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods   "GET, OPTIONS"
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers   "origin, authorization, accept"
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
>
> <Location />
>     AuthName "graphs restricted"
>     AuthType Basic
>     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd
>     <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
>       require valid-user
>     </LimitExcept>
> </Location>
> ```

And here is an issue that describes the config for creating a reverse proxy for Grafana with Apache:

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4136

If those links do not help, there are a lot of closed issues about this in the Grafana repo. Here is a search for cors and apache:

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed%20cors%20apache

Comment: Thank I'll try this and I tell you