# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in Node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors, grafana

I'm trying to use basic auth to login to my grafana page using Node.js and express, but it shows me an error like below.[image]

The 'localhost:4000' is holding my app.js and 'localhost:5000' is from nginx that proxy_pass to my grafana page(localhost:8080)

Here is my basic auth code

```
app.get('/grafana', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){
  console.log('Accessing to grafana');
  var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer('admin' + ":" + 'admin').toString("base64");
  request({
    url: 'http://localhost:5000',
    headers:{
      "Authorization": auth
    }             //passing through here
  }, function(err, resp, body){
```

what is my problem here..? I added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and etc like below, but doesn't work at all..

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Basic, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  next();
});
```

Does anybody have an idea for this...?

Thank you..

Comment: The error states that the client side code is trying to communicate with `localhost:8080` directly, not through the proxy on `localhost:5000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think, you should install `cors`.

```
npm install cors
```

Simple Usage :

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());


app.use(function (req, res, next) {

        // Website you wish to allow to connect
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        // Request methods you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

        // Request headers you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

        // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
        // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

        // Pass to next layer of middleware
        next();
    });
```

Can ref : [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)
more than : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! :) um.. I tried already using cors like 
var cors = require('cors');
var corsOption = { origin: 'http://localhost:4000'};
and I put app.use(cors(corsOption)); inside of the function(err, resp, body)

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to this [question about using an Apache proxy for Grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337877/change-grafanas-headers-access-control-allow-origin/42343318#42343318).

There is an example for nginx in the docs here:

http://docs.grafana.org/v1.9/installation/#graphite-server-config

```
auth_basic            "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file  /path/to/my/htpasswd/file;

if ($http_origin ~* (https?://[^/]*\.somedomain\.com(:[0-9]+)?)) {  #Test if request is from allowed domain, you can use multiple if
    set $cors "true";                                               #statements to allow multiple domains, simply setting $cors to true in each one.
}

if ($cors = 'true') {
    add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;           #this mirrors back whatever domain the request came from as authorized, as
    add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";          #as long as it matches one of your if statements
    add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, OPTIONS";
    add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, origin, accept";
}
```

How is your nginx proxy configured?

Comment: You forgot the "ifs are evil" https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/